# Accessing singleton model properties in another controller

Tags: model, singleton

I have a controller from which I am setting a property of my `model`

```
$model = Mage::getSingleton('foo/bar');
$model->setData('name', 'somename');
echo $model->getData('name');
```

This outputs the value `somename` in the same `Action`

If i try to access this property in another `controller Action` it is not getting the value

```
$model = Mage::getSingleton('foo/bar');
echo $model->getData('name');
```

I have created a block for my second controller Action and trying to access same property. But its not getting the value.

Model class is as follows (please ignore class name)

```
class Z_Foo_Model_Bar extends Varien_Object
{
    protected $_cacheTag = true;
    protected $_name = true;

    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

    }
    public function setName($val=''){
        $this->name = $val;

    }
    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getTest(){
        return 'one';
    }
}
```

I have a block method as follows

```
public function testsingle(){
        $model = Mage::getSingleton('foo/bar');
        echo $model->getTest();
        echo $model->getData('name');

    }
```

I am calling this method from my phtml file in second controller's block view file

```
$this->testsingle();
```

Still I am not getting the output 'somename' which is exptected

Reference [here from SO Alan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006183/magento-passing-data-between-a-controller-and-a-block)

Comment: Are you doing all this in one request or is the second controller action separate request?

Comment: second controller is a second request.I load the `first controller` click `submit` move to `second controller`. so they two different requests

Comment: Is it like for every request it creates a new object of the class even if we call `Mage::getSingleton`?

Comment: In that case you need to use session or have your model extend Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract

Comment: [read here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049575/magento-getsingleton-confusion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a slight conceptual gap in your understanding of magic setters/getters /getData() method in Magento and the singleton design pattern.

It seems like you expect the model to persist across different requests to two different controllers. However, the singleton pattern makes the object available/persistent only for the same request. Look at the definition of `Mage::getSingleton()` function to see how the singleton pattern works in Magento.

When you do $someModel->getData('param1'), Magento actually looks for the 'param1' key in _data property of your model object.

In your case when you do $someModel->setData('param1','value1'); You are setting it equivalent of something like:
$someModel->_data['param1'] = 'value1';

Your usage of the magic setter and getter is also not in line with Magento way of doing it. You don't need to write  magic getters and setters in Magento since they are already in place for you.